# Arranging 10 books on a shelf

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

There are 5 distinct computer science books, 3 distinct math books, and 2 distinct art books. How many ways are there to arrange all of these books on a shelf if every 2 of the 5 CS books are separated from each other by at least one other book?

I'm confused about the wording of this question and how to approach it. Is it saying that only 2 of the 5 CS books have to be separated?

Comment: Presumably, this means that two CS books cannot be next to each other.

Comment: It's a convoluted way of saying it, but I concur with Xander that it most likely means that no CS books are immediately next to one another.

Comment: Ok so since none of them can be together, this means that there are $5!$ ways to arrange the non-CS books, leaving 6 slots to put each CS book in. Then with the remaining 5 CS books, can I arrange them also in $5!$ ways? So answer= $5!5!$ Is this correct?

Comment: You are close.  You didn't choose which of the six slots are occupied by CS books.

Comment: Ive formulated another answer: $5!*6*5*4*3*2$, which is the same as $5!6!$

Comment: That is correct.  You put the non-CS books in order in $5!$ ways, then choose slots for the CS books one at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the $6$ possibilities to arrange $5$ indistinguishable CS books on a shelf of $10$ slots (if they cannot be neighbors):

[image]

If they are distinguishable then the number of possibilities is $6\times 5!$. On the remaining $5$ slots there are again $5! $ possibilities to arrange $5$ distinguishable books.

So, the final number is

$$6\times (5!)^2.$$